# How can I resolve this Error in refedit in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

When I select a cell in an excel sheet by a refedit and click on the arrow button in the following form:

[image]

and then click on the button again in that refedit

[image]

and select a cell, in the box there will be two cells that between them there is no comma(Although the address of the first cell sometimes  changes to the second cell but usually the address of the  first cell is not  deleted):

[image]

and if I want to use this string as  a range , this cause an Error. How can I solve this problem? By some addition code? or
Does my excel-2016 have a problem?

If I could clear the refedit when  the small window appear, that was very good. But the codes refedit.value="" or  refedit.delete do not work.

```
Private Sub RefEdit1_Change()

Dim ra11 As Range
Set ra11 = Range(RefEdit1.Value)
k = ListBox8.ListCount
Dim ra22 As Range
For Each ra22 In ra11
    ListBox8.AddItem
    ListBox8.List(k, 0) = sh2.Cells(ra22.Row, rff1p_s.Column)
    ListBox8.List(k, 1) = sh2.Cells(ra22.Row, icolsar1p(14))
    k = k + 1
Next ra22

End Sub
```

Comment: Sharing your code would have been nice

Comment: @VitaliyPrushak my code was added

Comment: That looks like a kind of glitch or improper work of RefEdit control - I was able to reproduce the behaviour, but unable to debug the code, as none of breakpoints were hit inside the code related to RefEdit events. As of quick suggestion, you may use a button instead with the code like this 'Set ra11 = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select range", Type:=8)'. This will open a range picker similar to RefEdit control and assign value to 'ra11' variable. But you will have to add some workarounds for Cancel button and empty range.

Comment: Thank you. This is a good way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **RefEdit** control in VBA has historically had the issue. The following `Exit` event code attempts to clean the text (range reference) when it is wrong. I hope the code is helpful.

```
Private Sub RefEdit1_Exit()
    Ref = Me.RefEdit1.Text
    If VBA.InStr(Ref, ",") = 0 Then
        If Len(Ref) - Len(Replace(Ref, "!", "")) >1  Then Me.RefEdit1.Text = ""
    Else
        For Each subRef In Split(Ref, ",")
            If Len(subRef) - Len(Replace(subRef, "!", "")) >1  Then
                Me.RefEdit1.Text = ""
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you but the above code does not solve the Issue (and the comma maybe  not appeared again). I decided I should not use the "change" event.  Because if I push the key "Ctrl" and select more than one cell (for example 2 cells), then there is 3 changes: one change after  the first select and two changes after the second select. (And I think anyone should not use the event "change' for refedits).

Comment: `If Len(Ref) - Len(Replace(Ref, "!", "")) = 2 Then Me.RefEdit1.Text = ""` This line handles the scenaio " the comma maybe not appeared again".

Comment: No. I tested it and it does not work. Furthermore there is 3 "if " but 2 "End if" in your solution. I put another "end if" in the line 4 but is does not work.

Comment: @JoJomax   
' Single-line `IF` syntax: `If condition Then [ statements ] [ Else [ elsestatements ] ]` . Please ref to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/if-then-else-statement?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461

Answer (score 1):

Following my comment, will add a workaround to avoid using a glitchy RefEdit control.

Prerequisites.
Controls:
-UserForm
-TextBox
-CommandButton

[image]

Variables:
-rangeToSet As Range - main range to be assigned
-inptResult As Range - InputBox result variable to perform the selection check
-isRangeSelected As Boolean - module global boolean variable for further checks

Usage:
Press the button and select range :)

The code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim isRangeSelected As Boolean

Private Sub selectRangeButton_Click()
Dim rangeToSet As Range
Dim inptResult As Range

Me.rangeTextBox.Text = ""

On Error Resume Next
Set inptResult = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select range", Type:=8)
Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0


If Not inptResult Is Nothing Then
    Set rangeToSet = inptResult
    isRangeSelected = True
    Me.rangeTextBox.Text = rangeToSet.Address
Else
    Me.rangeTextBox.Text = "The range is not selected"
    isRangeSelected = False
End If

End Sub
```